# Advantage of PWMs over an Oscillator based Induction Motor Drive

Tags: motor, pwm, oscillator, vfd

Variable Frequncy Drives commonly use pulse width modulation to generate frequencies for driving induction motors via the use of microcontrollers. Is there any advantage to using MC based PWM signals instead of an oscillator circuit (Wein Bridge?) to generate frequencies?

Comment: One of the advantages is being able to change the frequency, hence the rotor speed

Comment: What about a Wein Bridge Oscillator?

Comment: You can not provide enough Current output with Wien Br. Osc's. Also impedance matching makes it deadly hard to design such a system.

Comment: Neither can you provide enough current with a PWM. You have to amplify the signal. Correct?

Comment: Maybe yo should edit the Question. Maybe I did not get it. You can draw huge amount of currents form windings with transistors. PWM is just the way to make Transistors ON and OFF in given time. In PWM method, you determine the frequency  with adjusted delays with help of a uC. 
If you suggest using Oscillators to drive the transistors, then maybe, you can build a structure to adjust the delay between 2 or more oscillator outputs(But why the hussle?) and drive the transistor. But that would be unnecessarily inefficient and complex.

Answer (score 2):

AC Motor control requires both frequency and voltage control. The voltage must be proportional to frequency, but requires some increase over constant V/Hz at low frequency. When starting the motor, a frequency of about 2 or 3% of rated frequency is initially applied, then increased at a controlled rate.

To control both the frequency and voltage without PWM, a frequency-controlled power switching inverter must be supplied from a voltage-controlled power supply. That means coordinated control of two power conversion stages. Many VFD systems have been manufactured using several topologies including controlled-rectifier -- inverter, rectifier --chopper -- inverter and rectifier -- PWM inverter. The PWM inverter configuration has proven to be the most efficient and cost-effective system with the best performance in most respects. Therefore, that type of system is now used almost exclusively. However, variations in both the topology and the control strategy are currently in use and under development.

The control signals required from the microprocessor must ultimately generate driver signals for the power devices. Emulating the final output at a signal level does not do that.

Comment: So, if you double the frequency, then you have to use half as much voltage?  If you use half as much voltage, what happens to the torque?

Comment: No, if you double the frequency you double the synchronous speed, so you should approximately double the voltage too.Torque isn't directly related to voltage, but to current. If you add torque load, the motor will basically draw more current, but try to run at the same speed. (That current wastes more power in the motor, the TL/DR version is that it gets hotter and slows down a bit)

Answer (score 1):

The big advantage is efficiency.

If you start with a Wien bridge oscillator, you have a low power sinewave which you have to amplify. The amplifier would waste quite a lot of power.

With PWM, the signal you get from the PWM controller (usually in an MCU) is still low power, however it only has 2 values, 0 and 1. (or in some motor controller architectures, 3 values, -1,0,1).

You don't amplify these PWM signals, you merely use them to control switches, to connect +V, or -V, or disconnect power from the motor. This is more efficient as the switches are either fully on (a very low resistance) or fully off (transmitting no power) except for the moment of switching, which is kept as short as possible to minimise waste. The switches are usually MOSFETs, but IGBTs, bipolar transistors or GTO thyristors can be used too.

As far as actually controlling the motor, Charles has answered correctly that you need to control both frequency and voltage to avoid wasting power in the motor itself.

The highest efficiency you could get from a Class B amplifier delivering a sinewave is 78% and in practice you'd be lucky to reach 70%, and if you "turned down the volume" to reduce the output voltage at lower speeds, efficiency would be much lower still.

However a PWM motor controller can reach 90% efficiency or more, at any output frequency or voltage up to its design limit.